# What data type do I choose for storing plain text in Microsoft SQL Server 2008?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, string

For example, there is a string field Name in my C# (Linq-to-SQL); what data type would that SQL field have to be?

varchar? nchar? I'm confused.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### SQL Server 2005+ equivalent

The best SQL type equivalent to C# `String` is `nvarchar(max)`. It stores exactly the same amount of text as C# `String` object instance. But beware. Choosing other `[n][var]char` types would be more optimal on data store (meaning they could work much faster), but choosing one of these greatly depends on the data that you wish to store.

- `char(n)` is for fixed length strings (of length n) so if your strings don't vary in size, you would choose this type (i.e. product keys)
- `varchar(n)` is used for variable string lengths up to length of n (i.e. email address)
- `varchar(max)` is used for variable string lengths of whatever length up to 2G characters so basically the same as C# `String` type (i.e. blog post content)
- prepend **n** to these types and your data is stored in double bytes (unicode) so your strings are more versatile in multilanguage applications

### Pre SQL Server 2005

Before SQL Server version 2005, `[n]varchar(max)` types were not supported. You had to use `[n]text` types instead, but they were stored differently hence were much slower compared to `[n][var]char` alternatives and were also more cumbersome for developers to handle and manipulate.

Answer (score 1):

It could be any of the SQLServer types that store string data. So NVarchar, Varchar, Char, NChar.

In general, I choose to make anything text-related NVarchar, unles im 100% sure only latin charater set is needed in which case you can safely go with Varchar.

Comment: Don't forget text and ntext, although their usage is now deprecated.

Comment: Between those four you mentioned, which one do I choose? :\

Answer (score 1):

I always prefer to choose nvarchar: [Differences between varchar and nvarchar in SQL Server](http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/Differences-between-varchar-and-nvarchar-in-SQL-Server)

Answer (score 1):

- Varchar is the most common, but it is only used for ASCII text.
- NVarchar is the default for storing strings, because it works with Unicode.
- Char is fixed-length char.  It is pretty rare.  Almost nobody uses it any more.
- NChar is fixed-length unicode char.  I've never seen it used.
- Text and NText are unlimited binary storage for huge strings.  They cannot be indexed, so you might want to avoid them.

Comment: Should mention that for unlimited strings since SQL 2005 NVARCHAR(MAX) or VARCHAR(MAX) is the preference.